# BindingResolutionException when sending mails in Lumen Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, mailer

I have no problem sending synchronous mails, but the ones that get executed on a queue using Mail::queue throw the next error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [Swift_Transport] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Mail\Mailer, Swift_Mailer]. in /var/www/myapp.dev/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:804
```

Everything is configured correctly as emails are being sent when I do it synchronously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having so much trouble with sending emails inside of Lumen Jobs, I encapsulated the email sending in a Job which works with mailables like this:

**MailDispatcher.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailDispatcher extends Job {

    public $mail;

    public function __construct(Mailable $mail) {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }

    public function handle() {
        Mail::send($this->mail);
    }
}
```

Then when I want to queue a mail...

```
$mail = new MyMailableMail($user);
dispatch(new MailDispatcher($mail));
```

And it works correctly

Comment: Been struggling with this all evening and this did it. Thx

Comment: $app->make('queue'); will work as a charm, just add this to your app.php

Comment: Great! It worked!